# Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease' | keystore2.jks' not found for signing config 'release'

Tags: flutter, gradle, continuous-integration, github-actions, keystore

I am integrating Github action for CI/CD. But when workflow came to `flutter build apk --release` it fails with this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file '/home/runner/work/mobile_2/mobile_2/android/app/keystore2.jks' not found for signing config 'release'.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9m 46s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          589.5s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have already added keystore.jks to Github secrets.
The project doesn't contains any flovers like: release, debug etc.

On error message keystore file path is strange, mobile_2 is project name. As u can see there is it appears twice.

Anyway github action cannot build apk and appbundle as well. Any solutions are appreciated.

GitHub Action CI/CD workflow

```
name: Flutter CI + CD

# This workflow is triggered on pushes to the repository.
on:
  push: 
    branches: [ test ] # This will trigger the workflow on every push to the main branch
      
  # pull_request:
  #   branches: [ test ] # Add this trigger to run this workflow on PR's to the main branch
  #workflow_dispatch: # to manually run this workflow
  
env:
  FLUTTER_CHANNEL: 'stable' # 'stable', 'beta', or 'master', default to: 'stable'
  FLUTTER_VERSION: '3.10.0'
  XCODE_VERSION: '14.2'
  PATH_TO_AAB: 'build/app/outputs/bundle/release/mobile-release.aab'
  ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME: 'app.bundle.id'
  PATH_TO_IPA: 'build/ios/ipa/flutter_github_actions_basics.ipa'

jobs:
  code-analysis-and-testing:
    name: Code analysis and testing
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 30
    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set up Flutter
      uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
      with:
        channel: ${{ env.FLUTTER_CHANNEL }}
        flutter-version: ${{ env.FLUTTER_VERSION }} # you can also specify exact version of flutter
        
    - name: Get pub dependencies
      run: flutter pub get

    - name: Flutter analyze
      run: flutter analyze

    - name: Flutter test
      run: flutter test
  
  version:
    name:  Create version number
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Fetch all history for all tags and branches
      run: |
        git config remote.origin.url https://x-access-token:${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN_MOBILE }}@github.com/${{ github.repository }}
        git fetch --prune --depth=10000
    - name: GitTools
      uses: GitTools/actions/gitversion/setup@v0.9.10
      with:
          versionSpec: '5.x'
    - name: Use GitVersion
      id: gitversion
      uses: GitTools/actions/gitversion/execute@v0.9.10
    - name: Create version.txt with nuGetVersion
      run: echo ${{ steps.gitversion.outputs.nuGetVersion  }} > version.txt
    - name: Upload version.txt
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: gitversion
        path: version.txt
        
    - name: Get version.txt
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: gitversion
    - name: Create new file without newline char from version.txt
      run: tr -d '\n' < version.txt > version1.txt
    - name: Read version
      id: version
      uses: juliangruber/read-file-action@v1
      with:
        path: version1.txt
    - name: Update version in YAML
      run: sed -i 's/99.99.99+99/${{ steps.version.outputs.content }}+${{ github.run_number }}/g' pubspec.yaml
      
    
  android:
    name: Android CI/CD
    needs: code-analysis-and-testing
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
    timeout-minutes: 30
    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - name: Prepare key.jks & key.properties files
      env:
        KEYSTORE_FILE_BASE64: ${{ secrets.KEYSTORE_FILE_BASE64 }}
        KEY_PROPERTIES_FILE: ${{ secrets.KEY_PROPERTIES_FILE }}
      run: |
        echo "Convert key base64 string to a file"
        echo "$KEYSTORE_FILE_BASE64" >> key.jks.base64
        base64 --decode key.jks.base64 > key.jks

        echo "Convert key.properties secret string to a file"
        echo "$KEY_PROPERTIES_FILE" >> key.properties
      working-directory: 'android/'
     
    - name: Set up Flutter
      uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
      with:
        channel: ${{ env.FLUTTER_CHANNEL }}
        flutter-version: ${{ env.FLUTTER_VERSION }} # you can also specify exact version of flutter
    
    - name: Build AAB
      run: |
        flutter build appbundle --release
    
    - name: Upload AAB artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: release-aab
        path: ${{ env.PATH_TO_AAB }}

    - name: Flutter clean
      run: flutter clean

    - name: Flutter pub get
      run: flutter pub get
        
    - name: Build APK artifact
      run: flutter build apk --release

    - name: Create a Release in GitHub
      uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1
      with:
        artifacts: "build/app/outputs/apk/release/*.apk,${{ env.PATH_TO_AAB }}"
        token: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN_MOBILE }}
        tag: v1.0.${{ github.run_number }}
        commit: ${{ github.sha }}
        prerelease: true

    - name: Slack Notification
      uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@v2
      env:
        SLACK_CHANNEL: -dev-mobile-app
        SLACK_COLOR: ${{ job.status }} # or a specific color like 'good' or '#ff00ff'
        SLACK_ICON: https://github.com/rtCamp.png?size=48
        SLACK_MESSAGE: 'https://github.com/company-2/mobile_2/releases/download/v1.0.${{ github.run_number }}/mobile-release.apk'
        SLACK_TITLE: '${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}'
        SLACK_USERNAME: forTestingFromGitHubActions
        SLACK_WEBHOOK: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK_KEY }}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `/home/runner/work/mobile_2/mobile_2/android/app/keystore2.jks` file exists? Please include the relevant parts of your workflow in your question. Thanks!

Comment: how can i find it? where ```/home/runner/work/ ``` comes from?

Comment: I have just added workflow content, you can check it @Azeem

Comment: After checkout, you can use `ls -l /home/runner/work/mobile_2/mobile_2/android/app/keystore2.jks` in a separate step to verify this.

Comment: yes, as you said, there was not such file. But why it is searching for keystore file inside of it? I have added it to GitHub secrets, shouldn't it get keystore from secrets? or something wrong with my ci/cd pipline?

Comment: You have to create this file from secrets e.g. `echo '${{ secrets.SECRET_NAME }}` > /path/to/keystore2.jks'. Then, you can use it.